# Как получить кол-во миллисекунд до следующей недели в Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, время

У меня есть функция, которая должна вызываться каждый понедельник в 0:00
Как я думаю, для этого я должен использовать setTimeout.
Только я никак не могу понять, как мне получить количество миллисекунд до этой даты?
Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не нужно высчитывать миллисекунды.
Используйте пакет `node-schedule`, это что-то вроде cron для node.js.

Подробнее: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule

Answer (score 3):

```js
var d = new Date();
var nextMonday = new Date(d.getFullYear(),d.getMonth(), ( d.getDate() + 1 + (7-d.getDay())%7 ));
console.log("следующий понедельник " + nextMonday.toString() );

var timeout = nextMonday.getTime() - d.getTime();
console.log(`до понедельника осталось ${timeout} мс.`);
```

Comment: и не нужно никаких пакетов